# Sequence patterns

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Hi I'm new and I was wondering if a pattern could be derived from this. I wrote a program which printed all the numbers up until a number the user inputted, and then continuously deleted the middle number until none where left. I noticed a pattern in the totals and differences and was wondering if there are more. I would be delighted if one could be found: Here is an example with the inputted number being 10:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']          Total: 55 ,  ...
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', '10']          Total: 49 , Difference: 6
['1', '2', '3', '4', '7', '8', '9', '10']          Total: 44 , Difference: 5
['1', '2', '3', '4', '8', '9', '10']          Total: 37 , Difference: 7
['1', '2', '3', '8', '9', '10']          Total: 33 , Difference: 4
['1', '2', '3', '9', '10']          Total: 25 , Difference: 8
['1', '2', '9', '10']          Total: 22 , Difference: 3
['1', '2', '10']          Total: 13 , Difference: 9
['1', '10']          Total: 11 , Difference: 2
['1']          Total: 1 , Difference: 10
[]          Total: 0 , Difference: 1
```

Comment: What other patterns are you looking for? Naturally if you have a total, the number you pull from the sequence will do the same to the total.

Comment: The pattern is that the deleted number starts at about half the input and then oscillatingly the numbers below and above are eaten up. Hence the numbers deleted in odd steps and even steps, repsectively, form an increasing or decreasing sequenec ...

Comment: It seems that you are pulling out the number close to the average of the sum.

Comment: The pattern I noticed in the differences was it will alternate subtracting and multiply while going through the number line. So

Comment: -1, +2, -3, +4, -5, +6, -7, +8, -9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote the rows with an index $i \in \{ 0,1,2,\dots,n\} $. The row with $i=0$ is the "full row", the one with $i=n$ is the "empty row".

Note that the $i$-th row has $n-i $ elements, i.e. it is obtained by deleting exactly $i$ elements from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Consider the $i$-th row. Let $k$ denote the highest deleted number and $j$ the highest number in the first half of the row (the one such that $j+1$ is the lowest deleted number). We have $j=k-1$.

With this notation, the $i$-th has the form

$$ \{1,2,\dots,j, ' ', ' ', \dots, ' ', k+1, \dots, n \}. $$

Now we write $k$ in terms of $n$ and $i$.

- If $n$ is even, we have $ k = \frac{n}{2} + \lfloor \frac{i+1}{2} \rfloor $.
- If $n$ is odd, we have $ k = \frac{n}{2} + \lfloor \frac{i+1}{2} \rfloor  - \frac{1}{2}$.

Together, we have

$$  k = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} + \lfloor \frac{i+1}{2} \rfloor \rfloor. $$

Therefore

$$ j = k-i = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} + \lfloor \frac{1-i}{2} \rfloor \rfloor. $$

Now, the sum $S_i$ of the $i$-th row is

$$ S_i = \frac{n (n+1)}{2} - \left( (j+1) + (j+2) + \cdots + (j+i) \right) = \\
= \frac{n (n+1)}{2} - i j - \frac{i (i+1)}{2} = \\
= \frac{n (n+1)}{2} - \frac{i (i+1)}{2} - i (k-i) = \\
=  \frac{n (n+1)}{2} - \frac{i (i+1)}{2} - i \lfloor \frac{n}{2} + \lfloor \frac{1-i}{2} \rfloor \rfloor.   $$

Now we can find the $i$-th difference, $ 0<i \leq n$, that is

$$ d_i = S_{i-1} - S_{i} =  (i-1) \lceil \frac{i}{2} \rceil + i \lfloor \frac{1-i}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1. $$

As expected,

$$ d_i - d_{i-1} = (-1)^{i-1} (i-1). $$